# uploaded image url is not showing in browseable api of django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Following are the different parts of my Django rest API

### Project structure

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwmL.png)

### settings.py

```
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

...
```

### accounts/models.py/Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(validators=[contact_number_validator], max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('o', 'Owner'),
        ('c', 'Customer'),
        ('e', 'Employee'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=USER_TYPES,
        blank=True,
        default='c',
        help_text='User Role',
    )

    saloon = models.ForeignKey(Saloon, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}\'s profile'.format(self.user.username)
```

### api/views.py/UpdateUserProfileView

```
class UpdateUserProfileView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, CanUpdateUserProfile)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values(
            'user__username',
            'user__email',
            'user__first_name',
            'user__last_name',
            'user_type',
            'birth_date',
            'contact_number',
            'address',
            'profile_picture',
        )

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.request.user)
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=profile.user.id)

        user.username = serializer.validated_data['user__username']
        user.first_name = serializer.validated_data['user__first_name']
        user.last_name = serializer.validated_data['user__last_name']
        user.email = serializer.validated_data['user__email']
        user.save()

        profile.contact_number = serializer.validated_data['contact_number']
        profile.birth_date = serializer.validated_data['birth_date']
        profile.address = serializer.validated_data['address']
        profile.profile_picture = serializer.validated_data['profile_picture']
        profile.save()
```

### serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_picture = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user__username')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user__first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user__last_name')
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user__email')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'contact_number', 'birth_date', 'user_type',
            'address', 'profile_picture',
        )
        #fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user_type',)
```

### project level URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### Output

[api output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnjLT.png)

### Issue

Image URL is not showing in the output while
the image is successfully uploaded in the desired folder
and also the database is successfully updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this as I changed the *profile_picture* field in my serializers as shown below and add an extra field for URL and assigned the value to it in the separate field.
As far as I searched on google I came to find that this URL should be generated automatically but in my case, I have to build it manually.
If anybody knows the other way please do let me know.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_picture = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user__username')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user__first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user__last_name')
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user__email')

    profile_picture_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_profile_picture_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return request.build_absolute_uri(MEDIA_URL + obj['profile_picture'])

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'contact_number', 'birth_date', 'user_type',
            'address', 'profile_picture', 'profile_picture_url',
        )
        # fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user_type',)
```